# The same element name with different attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible in XSD to have the same elements with different attributes?

I tried something like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Type1">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="attribute1" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Type2">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="attribute2" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="address">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="elementName" type="Type1"/>
                <xsd:element name="elementName" type="Type2"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

How to do it? `address` element should be of `Type1` or `Type2`. Each type has different attributes.

Comment: So, your actual requirement is that an `elementName` has *either* an `attribute1` or an `attribute2` but not both?

Comment: Actually, having re-examined your schema (having not noticed the optional) - how is any XML processor meant to distinguish between something that produces a "type2" `elementName` with no attributes and a "type1" `elementName` in which `attribute1` is mandatory - I've no idea how I could identify this situation, as a human. How do you expect a computer to perform validation?

Comment: Computer could check whether first option fits or second. Check whether it is of type1 or of type2.

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work

See [3.8.6.3 Element Declarations Consistent in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#sec-cos-element-consistent).

In my words: Two elements in the same group have to have the same structure, there is no overloading by signature in XSD.

You will have to use the element name (or namespace) to differentiate between the two variants. This is also a good idea if you might want to use binding frameworks (JAXB or XmlSerializer) with your XML language. Those would most likely not be capable of handling your construct.

EDIT: Here an inheritance example following up our discussion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="Base" abstract="true">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Type1">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Base">
                <xsd:attribute name="attribute1" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Type2">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Base">
                <xsd:attribute name="attribute2" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="address" >
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="elementName" type="Base" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>            
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Untitled1.xsd">
    <elementName id="1" attribute1="123" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Type1"/>
    <elementName id="1" attribute2="123" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Type2"/>
</address>
```

This more or less does what you described, but requires you to add xxi:type attributes. I don't see the benefit.

Comment: Inheritance can help here? One base common element and then extend it for 2 types.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I meant by using different element names. Using two different extensions of a common complex type would "document" the intention, but it would not prevent (correctly implemented) schema processors from rejecting two elements with the same name and different structure.

Comment: You might be able to use xsi:type attributes together with inheritance (abstract type). But that basically would be very similar to using different names and I don't see an advantage either.

Comment: So it is not possible to do it what I want? I tried with inheritance and it passes validation, but everything is marked as wrong.

Comment: Can you post what you did?

If you declare a common abstract base type for Type1 and Type2 and use this base type to declare a new element replacing your xdd:choice, then you still have to somehow let the schema processor identify what concrete type can appear there.

Comment: Similar to wht I want, but in xml file xsi:type must be inserted? This is what changes my xml. That is not what I wanted.

Comment: More or less the same as what I edited above. Just add xsi:type attributes and it will validate.

However, I would suggest to defined top level elements for Type1 and Type2. You can then use one or the other (elementType1name, elementType2Name) and have the same semantics but less noise. Processing the XML with XPath is more intuitive and binding frameworks will happily create a reasonable object structure.

And yes, you definitely have to change your XML or to accept partial validation (not being able to restrict XML the way you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsd:complexType name="Base">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Type1">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Base">
            <xsd:attribute name="attribute1" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Type2">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="Base">
            <xsd:attribute name="attribute2" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="address">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="elementName" xml:base="Base"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The code, which passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

The "Element declarations consistent" constraint (which is present in both XSD 1.0 and 1.1) says that if two sibling elements have the same name, then they must have the same type. So the simple answer is no. However, in XSD 1.1 you could handle it by giving both elements the same type (a type which allows either of your attribute sets) and then defining additional constraints (on the parent element) using assertions.

Comment: How to do it? Could you give example?

Comment: You could for example define the child element with `type="xs:anyType"`, and on the parent element have an assertion such as `xs:assert test="childElem[1]/@att1 and not(childElem[1]/@att2 and childElem[2]/@att2 and not(childElem[2]/@att1)"`